# Not able to perform git checkout on local with origin/master

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I have a tool which updated my remote origin/master with some changes to my JAVA project.

On remote origin/master it deleted a folder and now I'm trying to update my local to test these changes.

I tried following commands in my local

`git pull origin master`

```
git fetch origin master & git reset --hard origin master

git fetch origin master & git checkout origin/master & git checkout -b newBranch
```

I see all the changes made by the tool. But the deleted folder is still in my local (which was deleted on my remote).

Comment: What is this tool you speak of? It updated your remote origin/master?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the directory is empty, then it is Ok. Git doesn't track empty directories, git only versions content (files).